# How to scrape text items from a dynamically loaded list

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I get to scrape the first 50 items (that are initially loaded when visiting the link) with this code rvest code

```
website <- "https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?title_type=feature&genres=crime"

page <- read_html(website)

links <- page |> html_nodes(".ipc-title-link-wrapper") |> html_attr("href") 

titles <- page |> html_nodes(".ipc-title__text") |> html_text("")
```

But when I clicked on "50 more" on the bottom of the page and refresh my code after that, the same 50 items as before are scraped - and not the 100,150,200,...etc. items that appear

How can I integrate them to be scraped as well or even scrape the entire list of all items mentioned on the top of the page (1-50 of 38.626)

Comment: "Robots and Screen Scraping: You may not use data mining, robots, screen scraping, or similar data gathering and extraction tools on this site, except with our express written consent" https://www.imdb.com/conditions fyi

Comment: I stand to be corrected but after looking at the page for the past 15 minutes, it looks like you'll need a package which allows you to run Javascript while scraping (which rvest does not). So either use that or imdb's api

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for looking at my issue. I m well aware of the imdb conditions. As I just use it for self-educational purposes, I think it s ok.

Besides, I was just wondering that the content is not even loaded into the page if I manually click the "50 mores" button. I haven t come across such thing before - but I am a novice to this...

Comment: Tom try switching off javascript in your browser, then refreshing the page. The extra data isn't loaded, and it's not in the source of the page